# Deleted rows removed from page but not from mysql database (PHP/jQuery)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm a complete beginner and have built a basic To-Do List application using PHP/jQuery. The application allows the user to add and remove tasks from a list (stored in a MySQL database).

I'm having issues with the delete function. When the delete button is clicked, it removes the task from the list but it must be remaining in the database, as it reappears once the page is refreshed.

I have no idea where I'm going wrong! Any help appreciated. See below code:

**index.php** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>To-Do List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" media="all" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="list">
            <ul>
                <?php
                    require("db_connect.php");

                    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tasks ORDER BY date ASC, time ASC");
                    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

                    if($numrows>0) {
                        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query ) ){

                            $task_id = $row['task_id'];
                            $task_desc = $row['task_desc'];

                            echo '<li><span>'.$task_desc.'</span><img id="'.$task_id.'" class="delete" width="10px" src="images/delete.png" /></li>';
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <form class="new" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="text" name="new-task" placeholder="Add a new task..." />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    add_task();
    delete_task();

    function add_task() {
        $('.new').submit(function() {
            var new_task = $('.new input[name=new-task]').val();

            if(new_task !== '') {
                $.post('add_task.php', { task: new_task }, function ( data ) {
                    $('.new input[name=new-task]').val('');
                    $(data).appendTo('.list ul').hide().fadeIn();
                    delete_task();
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    }

    function delete_task() {
        $('.delete').click(function() {
            var current_element = $(this);
            var task_id = $(this).attr('task_id');

            $.post('delete_task.php', { task_id: task_id }, function() {
                current_element.parent().hide().fadeOut("fast", function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

**delete_task.php** :

```
<?php
    $task_id = strip_tags( $_POST['task_id'] );
    require("db_connect.php");
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM tasks WHERE task_id='$task_id'");
?>
```

Comment: check the result of the mysql_query from your delete and check if the task_id is correctly submitted

Comment: Then why you wrote delete query. Instead of deleting put a status flag if status = 0 means delete. status = 1 means active. write an update query instead of delete

Comment: Mysql is depricated since PHP 7, you should really start using either Mysqli or PDO

Comment: @Ann-SophieAngermüller The result of the query is outputting a 1 but I'm also getting the following error: 'Notice: Undefined index: task_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\delete_task.php on line 2'

Comment: @egoodwin then take a look at ivan gajic answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your delete_task function. There is no such attr as 'task_id'. Try to replace

```
var task_id = $(this).attr('task_id');
```

With

```
var task_id = $(this).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides @IvanGajic answer is correct, also write your delete query like this:

```
mysql_query('DELETE FROM tasks WHERE task_id="' . $task_id . '"');
```